# Neo4j: Import csv - quote error, but no quotes in file

Tags: csv, neo4j

I would like to import a csv-file into neo4j. This file was created by myself using the Mac textedit.app. The options in my textedit.app are set in such a way that there is "no css".

When I try to import the file neo4j says:

At [URL] @ position 16471 -  there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That isn't supported. This is what I read: 'stylesheet"='

The problem is, there is no such line in the file. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue: the URL was a dropbox-URL, and instead of ?dl=0 one must state the option ?raw=1